# Angular and Django Rest framework. Issue with pagination in api

Tags: angularjs, django, django-rest-framework

I have a little problem.
In Rest framework settings I have:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    "DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES": ("rest_framework.permissions.IsAdminUser",),
    "PAGE_SIZE": 50,
    "DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES": (
        'rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication',
        'banner_compare.authentication.CsrfExemptSessionAuthentication',
    )
}
```

And in my API view, I have this line: (I have few pages in API, each pages has 50 elements)

```
 "next": "http://0.0.0.0:8000/api/something/?page=2",
```

In angular service:

```
  .factory('Something',["$resource", function ($resource){
return $resource(
    "/api/something/:something_id/", {something_id: '@id'},
    {
        query: {
            isArray: true,
            transformResponse: function (data) {
                var items = angular.fromJson(data);
                return items.results;
            }
        },
        update: {
            method: "PUT",
        }
    },
    {
        stripTrailingSlashes: false
    }
);
}])
```

And now, when I'll try to get all of this elements

```
$scope.somethings = Something.query();
```

I get only this 50 first elements. I get only first page from API.
How can I get all of this elements without something like this:

```
"PAGE_SIZE": 50000000,
```

:)

But also I want to have pagination in API view.

Answer (score 1):

Specify the `PAGINATE_BY_PARAM` in your `settings.py`:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    [...]
    'PAGINATE_BY_PARAM': 'page_size',
}
```

Then you can append something like `&page_size=42` on any request.

Comment: &page_size=42 but I'll not know this 'size' I always need to get all.

Comment: Oh.   For _specific_ queries where I want all the items, I use the above and just set `&page_size=∞` where ∞ is ridiculously large number like 42000000000.   Yeah, it isn't really ∞, but if you ever fetch 42 billion rows, your perf is toast anyways. If you really, really want to fetch ∞, then use the plugin at the [bottom of this doc page](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/pagination/#drf-extensions)

Comment: I've tried add PAGINATE_BY_PARAM, and in my controller I did this: Something.query({page_size:2000});
But it is still not working

Comment: What is `max_page_size` set to?  Is that limiting you?

Comment: i didn't set max_page_size, should I?

Comment: Its a configuration on your pagination to prevent malicious `page_size` requests.  [See docs](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/pagination/#configuration)

Comment: Hmm looks like `max_page_size` is [inifinity by default](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/pagination.py#L183)

Answer (score 0):

If I were you I would grab each successive page once the page is retrieved from the server. In this way your web app will be more responsive as well rather than waiting for a gigantic query.

For instance:

```
$scope.grabPage = function(page) {
    page = page || 1;
    Something.query(
      {page:page},
      function(result) {
        $scope.somethings = $scope.somethings.concat(result);
        $scope.grabPage(page + 1);
      }
    );
};
$scope.somethings = [];
$scope.grabPage();
```